# Координаты относительно других координат

Tags: c#, координаты, ref

Хочу получить массив, где нулевой элемент это Абсолютные координаты, а следующие это координаты относительно предыдущих. Изменяя координаты в одной ячейке должны изменятся все следующие.

| Хранятся в массиве | Считывается из массива |
| --- | --- |
| [10:5][1:1][2:4][2:2] | [10:5][11:6][13:10][15:12] |

Как мне написать структуру координаты что бы такое было возможно?

Мой псевдокод

```
struct Coordinats
{
    int x,y;
    ref относительноКоординат;
    public int X
        {
            get => относительноКоординат is null? x : x + относительноКоординат.X;
            set => x = value;
        }
    public int Y
        {
            get => относительноКоординат is null? y : y + относительноКоординат.Y;
            set => y = value;
        }
    


    public Coordinats(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    public Coordinats(int x, int y,  ref относительноКоординат)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.относительноКоординат = относительноКоординат;
        }
}
```

Comment: Так в чем.проблема? Псевдокод есть, допиливайте чтобы компилировалось

Comment: Не получается держать ссылку в структуре...тем более пустую. Не знаю куда копать чтобы решить эту проблему.

Comment: Так смените на класс, со ссылками на класс все проще. Сама структура данных - чисто связанный список, реализацию связанного списка найти - минутное дело, потом допилить под свою задачу и готово

Comment: Хотелось бы именно со структурой такое сделать. Как бы данных она содержит не много, и будет часто удаляться и создаваться новые.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С `ref struct` такое вряд ли получится реализовать. Потому что видимость экземпляров этих структур оказывается больше области (scope) их определения - вы же собираетесь хранить их в массиве (коллекции).

Тут нужно либо на классы переходить. Либо создать специальную коллекцию с желаемым поведением.

Навскидку код может быть таким:

```
public readonly struct Coordinate
{
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }

    public Coordinate(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

```
public class Coordinates : IEnumerable<Coordinate>
{
    private readonly List<Coordinate> _items;

    public Coordinates(params Coordinate[] items)
    {
        _items = new List<Coordinate>();

        foreach (var item in items)
            _items.Add(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<Coordinate> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return _items[0];

        int x = _items[0].X;
        int y = _items[0].Y;

        for (int i = 1; i < _items.Count; i++)
        {
            x += _items[i].X;
            y += _items[i].Y;
            yield return new Coordinate(x, y);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Можно реализовать `IList`, `ICollection` или любой другой подходящий интерфейс.
Все проверки входных параметров и количества элементов опущены ради краткости.

```
var coordinates = new Coordinates(
    new Coordinate(10, 5), new Coordinate(1, 1), new Coordinate(2, 4), new Coordinate(2, 2)
);

foreach (var coord in coordinates)
    Console.WriteLine(coord.X + " " + coord.Y);
```

---

Можно добавить свойство начальную координату:

```
public class Coordinates : IEnumerable<Coordinate>
{
    private readonly List<Coordinate> _items;

    public Coordinate Origin { get; set; }

    public Coordinates(params Coordinate[] items)
    {
        _items = new List<Coordinate>();

        foreach (var item in items)
            _items.Add(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<Coordinate> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return Origin;

        int x = Origin.X;
        int y = Origin.Y;

        for (int i = 0; i < _items.Count; i++)
        {
            x += _items[i].X;
            y += _items[i].Y;
            yield return new Coordinate(x, y);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

```
var coordinates = new Coordinates(
    new Coordinate(1, 1), new Coordinate(2, 4), new Coordinate(2, 2)
);
coordinates.Origin = new Coordinate(10, 5);

foreach (var coord in coordinates)
    Console.WriteLine(coord.X + " " + coord.Y);
```

Comment: "Потому что видимость экземпляров этих структур оказывается больше области (scope) их определения".  Можно подробнее в этом месте?  Какая разница где находится экземпляр структуры(поле объекта/ячейка массива)?

Comment: @03MegaPixel - `ref struct` можно использовать только в пределах одного stack frame. Такой тип не может быть помещён в кучу, даже как член массива или поле класса.